# Autoload classes for testing from separate directory

Tags: phpunit, composer-php

Consider the following project layout:

```
/lib/
    Folders/For/Namespaces/SomeClass.php
/test/
    Folders/For/Namespaces/SomeClassTest.php
composer.json
```

And this extract from `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MyNamespace\\" : "lib/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "test": "phpunit --bootstrap vendor/autoload.php tests"
}
```

This allows me to run `composer test` which will execute `SomeClassTest.php` among others and `\MyNamespace\Folders\For\Namespaces\SomeClass` is found by the autoloader.

When building an abstract test case though, I can not get autoloading to work:

```
/test/
    Folders/For/Namespaces/SomeClassTest.php
    AbstractTest.php
```

Here `\MyNamespace\Folders\For\Namespaces\SomeClassTest` extends `\MyNamespace\AbstractTest` but this is not found by the autoloader. The reason is obvious, because in `composer.json` the `test/` directory is not linked to the namespace. But how can I make this work?

I tried moving `\MyNamespace\AbstractTest` to `\MyNamespace\Test\AbstractTest` and adding this namespace to `composer.json` like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MyNamespace\\" : "lib/",
        "MyNamespace\\Test\\" : "test/"
    }
},
```

But this did not help. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

I might be too late for the answer, but still.

### Solution for the problem

Put `AbstractTest` class into `\MyNamespace\Test` namespace. 
That would make it work with your auto-loader configuration:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MyNamespace\\" : "lib/",
        "MyNamespace\\Test\\" : "test/"
    }
},
```

---

### Development-time auto-loader

Please use [autoload-dev](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload-dev) section to define *development-time* auto-loader configuration:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MyNamespace\\" : "lib/",
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MyNamespace\\Test\\" : "test/"
    }
},
```

Comment: Thank you. This has helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you need some namespaces only for your tests, you can use `spl_autoload_register` to autoload them manually.
See http://php.net/manual/de/function.spl-autoload-register.php

In case of PHPUnit, I you can create a Bootstrap.php in which you can handle your autoloading. This code sample:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    $path = str_replace('\\', '/', $className);
    $testNs = 'MySeparate/Namespace';
    $testNsLength = strlen($testNs);
    if(substr($path, 0, $testNsLength) == $testNs) {
        include_once '/path/to/src/'.$path.'.php';
    }
});
```

would implement a psr-4 autoloading of a separate namespace.